# Scale Codec for Dart

Tags: polkadot-js, scale

There are a couple of packages that are outdated or do not have the features I need for Dart-lang. So, I decided to code my own. There are really good implementations coded in various languages that are mentioned in the [Substrate Docs](https://docs.substrate.io/v3/advanced/scale-codec/#implementations).

My plan is to understand how it's coded and try to migrate it into Dart. One of the limitations of the Dart is the lack of unsigned integers.

I can Encode and Decode basic values for now. However, I don't really understand how to decode metadata.

Where should I look for metadata decoding in `@polkadot/api` or in any other languages?

Any suggestions or ideas would be great!

Answer (score 3):

https://docs.substrate.io/v3/advanced/scale-codec/ is really enough to implement it completely.

Otherwise, here is [TypeScript implementation](https://github.com/subsquid/squid/tree/master/scale-codec) we use at [subsquid.io](https://subsquid.io), which will be probably easier to understand than the one from [polkadot.js](https://github.com/polkadot-js/api/tree/master/packages/types-codec).

Edit:

Somehow missed the metadata part of the question.

Metadata is a regular scale-encodable data-structure, which is supposed to be well known. You can have a look at its definition [here](https://github.com/subsquid/squid/blob/49e3c9e72e9f1d7bc267b1174139fc92b5defd15/substrate-metadata/src/old/definitions/metadata/index.ts#L20). Its canonical encoding beside "regular bytes serialised by scale" also includes a [special magic number](https://github.com/subsquid/squid/blob/49e3c9e72e9f1d7bc267b1174139fc92b5defd15/substrate-metadata/src/codec.ts#L18) prefix.

Comment: Your implementation is way more straightforward than other ones, IMHO. I migrated this to Dart and it works great! The only failing test is `-100_i8`. I'll investigate further once I got my coffee :)